# When changing states browser doesn't find project js files

Tags: angularjs, gulp, yeoman, gulp-inject

I am trying to create a new state in angular using ngRouter.
I have an `index.route.js` file that contains the following:

```
(function() {
'use strict';

 angular
.module('testApp')
.config(routeConfig);

/** @ngInject */
function routeConfig($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
      .state('home', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'app/main/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
      })
      .state('tools', {
        url: '/tools/:category',
        templateUrl: 'app/tools/tools.html',
        controller: 'ToolsCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'tsCtrl'
      });

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

}
})();
```

Then, I have created a `tools.html` and a `tools.controller.html`.

`tools.html`:

## Hello World

`tools.controller.js`:

```
(function(){
'use strict';

angular
.module('testApp')
.controller('ToolsCtrl', ToolsController);

/** @ngInject */
function ToolsController(){
    var ctrl = this;
    ctrl.tools = {};
    //TBD: more code.
}
})();
```

The problem is that whenever I go to for example `http://localhost:3000/tools/maps`, the browser complains that it can't find some of the js files that are suppose to be linked to the project. Now, the link it shows contains the state, for example instead of searching for bootstrap in `http://localhost:3000/app/index.route.js` it searches for it in `http://localhost:3000/tools/app/index.route.js`. Why is that?

I have used Yeoman with the gulp-angular generator in order to create the project.

Comment: Replace your relative paths with absolute paths: /css/bootstrap.min.css instead of css/bootstrap.min.css

Comment: The paths are automatically being generated using gulp-inject..

Comment: @JBNizet I updated my question to be more specific

Comment: Then fix the gulp file, or use a base tag (which is mandatory by default when html5Mode is used).

Comment: I'm trying to do something very basic so I have a feeling that I am doing something wrong rather than that there is a problem in the gulp file.. Does the code seem ok to you?

Comment: With a base tag, you shouldn't have this problem. Read https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#relative-links. If you configured the $location service to be in html5Mode and to not check for a base tag, then it's your responsibility to make sure all the links are absolute and not relative.